# Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $0→A→B→C→0$ be an exact sequence of $R$ module. In general, $A \otimes_R N→B \otimes_R N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, exact-sequence, flatness

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $0→A→B→C→0$ be an exact sequence of $R$ module.
In general, for any $R-$module $N$,$A \otimes_R N→B \otimes_R N$・・・① is not always injective,

My question is, if **$C$ is flat** $R-$module, can we say ① is always injective ?
I'm stuck with how to use flatness and exactness to prove ① is injective.
If this is a famous fact, reference(book, pdf,etc・・・) is also appreciated.

Comment: How are you defining flat module? Because Wikipedia uses this property practically as the definition of "flat $R$-module." Specifically, $0\to A\to B$ exact means $A\to B$ is injective. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module

Comment: @ThomasAndrews are you sure? It's not the module that we tensor with that is assumed to be flat here.

Comment: This is a standard fact. For example, it’s proposition 1.2.6 in Liu’s *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*.